# unable to mail correct charset from svn log output with accented characters

Tags: svn, ant, character-encoding

I generate a svn log file using ant and then send the result with the mail task.  I'm unable to set the correct character encoding.  When I open the message with outlook, the accented characters are displayed incorrectly.

The output file is in cp850 (based on my cmd shell)

```
D:\MEP>chcp
Active code page: 850
```

The ant task is

```
   <target name="test">
    <exec executable="svn" output="logresult.txt">
    <arg line="log -g src" />
    </exec>
    <mail mailhost="mail.xxxxxx.xx" subject="Test character-encoding"
          tolist="sxxxxx@xxxxx.com" 
          messagefile="logresult.txt">
      <from address="ant@xxxxx.com"/>
    </mail>
    </target>
```

I tried to change the svn log output encoding... without success.
I tried to set "charset" prop on the mail task... without success.

Any i18n tricks ?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoding was not working on mail tag.

I ended up to use "iconv" to convert output from cp850 to iso-88590-1.

Answer (score 0):

Try attribute encoding which is default set to auto (see [ant manual mail task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mail.html)):

```
 <mail mailhost="mail.xxxxxx.xx" subject="Test character-encoding"
  tolist="sxxxxx@xxxxx.com" 
  messagefile="logresult.txt"
  encoding="plain">
  <from address="ant@xxxxx.com"/>
 </mail>
```

Some new ant task for reencoding textfiles might come in handy too =>
[Reencode 0.1](http://thewonggei.wordpress.com/)